# Cropping an image for use in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How should I crop an image to use in a `tikzpicture`?

I declare an image in my header

```
\pgfdeclareimage{myimage}{image.png}
```

Then I want to use a cropped version of `myimage` in a tikzpicture

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [...things being drawn...]
    \pgfuseimage{image}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there an option akin to `\includegraphics[trim={0 1cm 0 0}]{image}`?

Comment: why not `\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[trim={0 1cm 0 0}]{image}};`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `\includegraphics` command can be used in node's contents part, therefore if `\includegraphics[trim={0 1cm 0 0}]{image}` is the desired solution, just insert it into a `node`:

```
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[trim={0 1cm 0 0}]{image}};
```

`inner sep=0pt` is included to avoid any empty space between the image and node's border.